# bootstrap input component with asp.net textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use twitter bootstrap input component for a textbox which is present [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/). How could I use it with my ASP.Net text box?

Actual code:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="text" Text="<span class=\"input-group-addon\">@</span>" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">

    </asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I've been using this type of code with no problems:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  <asp:TextBox ID="text" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username">
  </asp:Textbox>
</div>
```